# Open Graph Spanish

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

Hi guys I have a simple question, I am developing a new app, I want to use the Open Graph Actions, Objects and Aggregations, Tha app I'm developing is in Spanish, so can I submit this using this language?? or I need to translate using Localize??

Thanks Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this by

```
 <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
```

Source  [**Open Graph Internationalization**](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/internationalization/)